# Send string to HM-10 ble in arduino from xamarin app and receiving different one

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to do a tx(pc)-rx(arduino), tx(arduino)-rx(pc) connection, sending a string "Hello World!:)" from the client in xamarin.forms, in order to receive the same string decoded from serial port with BLE. At the moment I send the string, it works well, due to the fact that I see perfectly the string on Serial Monitor of arduino, but when decoded, the string is not the same as the sended.

Codes:
Arduino:

```
void loop(){
  if (BT.available() > 0 ){

    c = BT.readString();
    
    str_len = c.length() +1;
    char char_array[str_len];
    c.toCharArray(char_array, str_len);
    int i = 0;
    while(i<str_len){
      char_array_aux[i] = char_array[i];
      i++;
    }
    char_array_aux[str_len] = "\n";
    
   
      }
     
      int i = 0;
      while(i<str_len){
        if(char_array_aux[i] == "\n")
          BT.end();
        BT.print(char_array_aux[i]);
        i++;

      }
      
      
    
  }
```

Xamarin.forms app send/receive message function:

```
public async Task sendAndReceiveString()
        {
            //Guid characteristics =    Id  {0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}  System.Guid
            //Guid services =   Id  {0000ffe0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}  System.Guid

            var stringToSend = "Hello World! :)";
            var services = await deviceConn.GetServicesAsync();
            IService service = services[0];
            var characteristics = await service.GetCharacteristicsAsync();
            var characteristic = characteristics[0];
            try
            {

                //Write message
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringToSend);
                
                await characteristic.WriteAsync(bytes);

                //Read Message
                

                byte[] answ = await characteristic.ReadAsync();
                string answ_str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(answ);
                


                msgSended = "Message sended:" + stringToSend;
              
               
                        msgReceived = "Message received: " + answ_str;
            }
```

Debug log:

```
Sended string: Hello world! :) 

Received string: Hello world! :)
Hello world! :)
He
```

I do not know how to work properly with bluetooth buffer. If anybody knows, let me know it please.

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Raúl.

Comment: Just to confirm that I understand your problem correctly: You successfully write `Hello World` from your app via Bluetooth to your Arduino and it gets printed to serial. Now you want to send a string from the Arduino back by writing to serial and sending it via Bluetooth. Correct? Have you checked what the Arduino thinks you wrote to the console by printing `Serial.read()` before sending it?

Comment: That's exactly what I want. I tried to Serial.write(BT.read()) and it prints perfectly the string sended from the xamarin client ("Hello World ! :)"). But I do not know how to resend this string from the serial of the arduino via Bluetooth back to the client on xamarin.

Comment: Do you want to send it immediately as soon as you received it? you could save the received character like this: `char c = BT.read();` and immediatly print and send it like this: `Serial.write(c); BT.write(c);`

Comment: I tried what you said and this is the result string returned to the client: Hc��oc-2�)�. If I only Serial.write(c) without BT.write(c), serial monitor returns correctly de string Hello World! :)

Comment: I am using ASCII encoding for both encoding and decoding.

Answer (score 2):

I just fixed it! I just used `BT.readStringUntil("\n");` instead of `readString()`

and buffer does not overflow.